# Vagrant IP address setup for port listening

Tags: linux, redirect, vagrant, vagrantfile, ifconfig

I run this command inside my vagrant instance:

`printf 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved\r\nLocation: https://www.eff.org/' | nc -l 2345`

On my host computer, I want to access `<ip of my vagrant server>:2345` and be redirected to https://www.eff.org/.
Redirect does not happen, the browser just keeps loading.

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network "public_network" 
  
end
```

**How to set up Vagrantfile and determine the IP address of the vagrant Linux server, to use in the browser on the host machine using port 2345?**

I have tried:

- `curl ifconfig.me`, got: `46.128.200.193`
- `hostname -i`, got: `2a02:2455:25f:e000:a00:27ff:febd:cd6c%4` `10.0.2.15` `192.168.33.10` `192.168.0.16`
- `ifconfig`, got:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:5f:bb:e6  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe5f:bbe6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:815 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:590 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:83632 (83.6 KB)  TX bytes:80621 (80.6 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:c0:4e:f3  
          inet addr:192.168.33.10  Bcast:192.168.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec0:4ef3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:819 (819.0 B)  TX bytes:2040 (2.0 KB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:bd:cd:6c  
          inet addr:192.168.0.16  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:2455:25f:e000:a00:27ff:febd:cd6c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:febd:cd6c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:412 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31706 (31.7 KB)  TX bytes:8356 (8.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:888 (888.0 B)  TX bytes:888 (888.0 B)
```

On my host machine, I have tried accessing in the browser:

- `192.168.33.10:2345`, got:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.33.10:2345
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

- `10.0.2.15:2345`, got nothing
- `46.128.200.193:2345`, got nothing

But no setup of Vagrantfile and combination of ip addresses with port 2345 have redirected me to eff.org so far.

Comment: What is your virtual machine provider?

Comment: @VladVolkov Virtual Box

Answer (score 1):

> How to set up Vagrantfile and determine the IP address of the vagrant
> Linux server, to use in the browser on the host machine using port
> 2345?

To access a port in your vagrant machine from your host machine (also known as port-forward), you need to add these lines under your `configure("2")` section:

```
config.vm.define "server" do |server|
    server.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2345, host: 2345
end
```

As for the IP, I'm not sure how you could know it from your host without checking inside the vagrant machine, but I'm pretty sure the IP `10.0.2.15` should be accessible to you from the host (and vice-versa, the IP `10.0.2.2` should be used in the vagrant machine to access the host).

Answer (score 0):

I have different approach.
I am using python simple http server module.

code is used from [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506932/how-do-i-forward-a-request-to-a-different-url-in-python)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

class myHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
   def do_GET(self):
       self.send_response(301)
       self.send_header('Location','http://www.eff.org')
       self.end_headers()

theport = 1234
Handler = myHandler
pywebserver = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", theport), Handler)

print "Python based web server. Serving at port", theport
pywebserver.serve_forever()
```

### regarding multiple interfaces.

make sure output of

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

*:1234 i.e. all interfaces are used to serve on this port.

```
web_fwd.p 2594         dev    3u  IPv4  60354      0t0  TCP *:1234 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Amit Side's answer, a Vagrant guest/instance has its own virtual network: Making a service available on a guest/instance's port (`2345` in your question) is only visible on that guest/instance's virtual network unless you also add port forwarding as suggested in that answer.